# Where are available Roles Defined in the wp_ database?

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I got on the list to test a private beta of a plugin I'm using on a multisite network.

The plugin authors have code in there to add a custom role. They have a bug that removes the ability to give a user any role except their one custom role.

When I visit `../wp-admin/network/site-users.php`, the "Add User" role pulldowns only show the one role this plugin added. The change role pulldown menu shows all the WP default roles, plus a few extra roles this and other plugins have added. If I attempt to change a user to one of these roles, I get a "You can't give users that role" error page.

I've been discussing this with the developer, and they seem baffled.

I've been looking through my database and the codex, and I can't find where the valid roles are defined.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

User roles are stored in `wp_options` table.

search for option name  `wp_user_roles` in the `wp_options` table.

Comment: Please note that the `option_name` may contain your DB prefix instead of `wp_`. This was the case for my database.

Comment: Might also have a blog id if you're on multisite, eg "wp_37_user_roles".

Comment: Yes, if you're on multisite and have a blog ID, the table AND the option_name would include the blog ID. So use e.g. this query: `select * from wp_37_options where option_name = 'wp_37_user_roles';`

Answer (score 25):

User Roles are stored in table `wp_user_meta`

To check user roles, first, check out the user id in the table `wp_users` (Column name ID)

Now Go to table `wp_usermeta` and search where column `user_id` is equal to the ID that matches `ID` from `wp_users` table.

You will get a list of rows with metadata of the chosen user, the row with `meta_key` as `wp_capabilities` defines the user role.

The Value of `wp_capabilities` for

- Admin : `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`
- Woo Commerce Customer :  `a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}`

Comment: Your answer relates to the *assignment* of a role to a user. The OP was asking about the role definitions themselves, which are stored in wp_options.

Comment: that a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} is kind of a messy string, what's all the fluff numbers around the meat?

Comment: @Johnny Rockex That is _serialised data_ a way to store more than one value in a database cell... often frowned upon to an extent, as it can make life more difficult. The "s" stands for "string" (of 13 character) the "b" is for Boolean - Google Data Serialisation in MySQL for details.

Comment: @mayersdesign I can understand the frowns, my gut would lean towards restructuring the tables to have single values in each field, but who knows, it works.